# Change multiple date values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple input fields with the same html class.

The value is a string.

I would like to add the same value to all of these dates with jQuery.

This is my html:

```
<input type='text' class='date' value='2018-12-01'>
<input type='text' class='date' value='2018-10-07'>
```

This is the jQuery that's not working:

```
$(".date").val(function() {
    return this.value + this.value;
});
```

The result should be:

```
<input class='date' value='2018-12-012018-12-01'>
<input class='date' value='2018-10-072018-10-07'>
```

How can this be done? Best regards Kresten

Comment: When do you want to do this? On page load? on click to some button? When value entered?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Your jquery appeared all good to me so I created an answer to test it out.  Sure enough no problems.  If you are experiencing a specific issue please update your question.

Comment: Just out of immense curiosity, what are you trying to do with `2018-12-012018-12-01`??

Comment: I'm trying to make pagination. On a click next button all dates in a page will change with + one year. the example here was just to simplify the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapped your function in a button click for demonstration purposes and it appears to work as expected.  It is possible that `jQuery` is not linked or that another library has taken over the `$` qualifier, in this case use `(jQuery)` instead of `$`.

This [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) describes the behaviour.

Original;

```js
$("#run").click(function() {
  $(".date").val(function() {
    return this.value + this.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='date' value='2018-12-01'>
<input type='text' class='date' value='2018-10-07'>
<button id='run'>Run</button>
```

Without using `$`;

```js
(jQuery)("#run").click(function() {
  (jQuery)(".date").val(function() {
    return this.value + this.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='date' value='2018-12-01'>
<input type='text' class='date' value='2018-10-07'>
<button id='run'>Run</button>
```

Comment: I can't make it work. it's inside a Word Press site. Would that change anything?

Comment: It is possible that the use of `$` has been usurped by another library.  I have updated my answer to account for that.

Comment: `(jQuery)` why? simply pass the `$` alias as argument. `jQuery(function($) {/*DOM READY AND $ ALIAS SECURED*/});`

Comment: Sorry, your code was working just fine. Thanks. I just found out now. I was looking for the changes inspecting the pages HTML, but of course, it won't appear there.